# how to user nl2br function with htmlspecialchars in phpmysql

Tags: php

How to insert `nl2br` function with `htmlspecialchars`? I have a site where input is taken from textarea and `nl2br` is used to convert next line to a paragraph. When I tried with `htmlspecialchars` I got the below output. Here I wrote three 'test' words in textarea and saved in database. I am using `htmlspecialchars` to prevent html injections but because of this function `nl2br` function is not working. Can you tell be how to work around this problem?

```
test<br/>test<br/>test<br/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yo do:

```
htmlspecialchars(nl2br($text));
```

you need:

```
nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text));
```

Answer (score 4):

Call `nl2br` *after* you call `htmlspecialchars`:

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($the_text));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's about using the right order,

htmlspecialchars(nl2br($string)); will produce the result you describe.
nl2br(htmlspecialchars($string)); will produce the result you wish.

Answer (score 2):

**nl2br**

> Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

**htmlspecialchars**

> Convert special characters to HTML entities

```
$text = "Hello \n World";
$unexpected_result = htmlspecialchars(nl2br($text)); // => "Hello &lt;br /&gt; World"
$expected_result   = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text)); // => "Hello <br/> World"
```

... That's why we need to use use **htmlspecialchars** before **nl2br**